# PostgreSQL - Index not used

Tags: database, postgresql

I have created a table.

And I've written a procedure to update the table when I update another table.

That is, when I update table2 few records from the table2 will be updated to `table1` using the trigger I've created on `table2`.

I could've created view instead of doing that. But the main purpose of it is I won't be able to create index on views.

Hence I did like this. Table2 consists about 500k rows. And I'm updating about 220k rows to  and a extra column is created on some calculation that'll give each rows either `0` or `1` based on some criteria.

And I've created a index on the `table1`.

If I execute a `count(*)` query in `table2` in which i already have only one index for `date` col. The query executes in 200ms which has about 500k rows.

But if I execute the same query on `table1` it takes double the time when compared to that of `table2`.

And if I remove the index on `table1` it add another 500-600ms to the execution time.

Creating index on `table1` has just reduced `500-600ms`.

Explain Analyze of the query with 2 columns.

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=80421.85..80422.94 rows=73 width=4) (actual time=6248.826..6248.829 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..70306.88 rows=2022994 width=4) (actual time=0.048..4203.224 rows=2022994 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((date >= '2014-02-01'::date) AND (date <= '2014-04-30'::date))"
"Total runtime: 6248.895 ms"
```

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  label1 text NOT NULL,
  label2 text NOT NULL,
  label3 text NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  "mobile no" bigint NOT NULL,
  "start time" time without time zone NOT NULL,
  "end time" time without time zone NOT NULL,
  label4 text NOT NULL,
  label5 text NOT NULL,
  value1 integer NOT NULL,
  count numeric NOT NULL
)
```

Index Definition :

```
CREATE INDEX ix_date
  ON table1
USING btree
  (date);
```

And the `COUNT(*)` I've given is just for an example.

Actually I sum up the `count` column by grouping label1, 2, 3 and extracting the month from date.

Comment: Please show us the definition of the table and the indexes (`CREATE TABLE ...`, `create index...`). And show us the query you are using.

Comment: Also make sure that your statistics are up to date: `vacuum analyze table1; vacuum analyze table12;` (and don't name your columns `date` )

Comment: You say "I've created a index on the table1" but we need to see exactly how it was created to make sure it was done correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But updated with the required info.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

> I could've created view instead of doing that. But the main purpose of it is I won't be able to create index on views.

Views are "expanded" when processing queries so, e.g. a `SELECT x FROM my_view JOIN y...` will practically directly substitute the view definition inside your query, and the resulting expanded query will be able to use any indexes directly, if applicable.

Secondly,

> If I execute a count(*) query in table2 in which i already have only one index for date col. The query executes in 200ms which has about 500k rows.

Unfortunately, COUNT(*) queries in PostgreSQL don't usually use indexes, even in recent (9.2+) versions with index-only scans. See here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F for a description why is that. A non-unique (or primary key) index will NEVER be used for `COUNT(*)`.

Thirdly, updating records in a MVCC database such as PostgreSQL creates updated copies of those records, instead of updating them in-place. This almost always results in significant internal data fragmentation, which is sorely visible if you use drives with slow seek times, like mechanical drives. If you want linearly reduced COUNT(*) times between tables of different sizes, either make sure the data is not fragmented (`VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` + `REINDEX` will mostly do the trick), or just use an SSD.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I've just given an example `COUNT(*)`. But actually I don't use an INDEX for Count alone. And moreover There is a time difference in the `COUNT(*)` too when I apply the index or I remove it. And moreover I can just blindly say the you didn't understand my query over here. I no where speak about the advantage and disadvantage of creating a view. All I wanted here is to make the query run in `ms`. If that was a view I can never do it because the data is about 200k to 250k. Hope you understand my query now.

Comment: And I did try `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE + REINDEX` but no changes. Still taking the same time.